# How long do I need to wait for Mandrill to send a POST request to my endpoint whenever an email is received by a route?

Tags: mandrill

I'm trying to test inbound email. I've setup a webhook, and deployed an endpoint that receives POST requests from Mandrill. I also have the mx records and routes setup. I also clicked on the "test" button and it passed.

So I sent emails to the route I configured an hour ago, and I still don't receive any post requests from mandrill.. How long should I wait? :(

This is inbound email by the way. Not outbound.

Answer (score 0):

Inbound POSTs should definitely come within a few minutes - it's not real-time, but should be pretty quick. Would recommend looking for a messages/inbound API call in your account [API Logs](https://mandrillapp.com/settings/api) to see whether it's being processed and associated with your account (that will also tell you the route matched to confirm that the match is working as expected). If you're still having trouble or you don't see it in your account API Logs, you'll want to get in touch with support so they can investigate the specific domain and your account.